# Controlling an AsynTaskLoader using a button click

Tags: java, android, listview, button, loader

I have created an app that displays a list of 10 books based on a query keyword entered by the user.

I have used an `EditText` View for the user to enter the query.

I have also used an `ImageButton` for the search button.

I have used a custom class that extents `AsyncTaskLoader` to load content to my `ListView`.

I have called the `initloader()` method from the MainActivity of the app and has called my custom loader from the `OnCreateLoader` override method.

I want the loader to fetch the data only on a button click and not automatically when the activity starts.

Main Activity

```
package com.example.shara.booklistapp;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.app.LoaderManager.*;
import static com.example.shara.booklistapp.BookQueryUtils.LOG_TAG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Blist>> {
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;
    private String Book_list_request_url = "Michael Jackson";
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private NetworkInfo networkInfo;
    private TextView emptytextview;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView booklistview = findViewById(R.id.list);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Blist>());
        booklistview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        emptytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptytextview);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.search_query_text_view);
        booklistview.setEmptyView(emptytextview);
        booklistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Blist currentBook = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Uri currentbookk = Uri.parse(currentBook.getUrl());

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, currentbookk));
            }
        });

        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    //Overriding the abstract methods of the Loadermanager
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Blist>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, Book_list_request_url);
        return new BlistLoader(this, Book_list_request_url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Blist>> loader, List<Blist> blists) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Using the networkInfo variable declared earlier to check whether the system has internet connectivity and displays a message if there isn't one.
        if (networkInfo == null) {
            emptytextview.setText(R.string.no_network);
        } else {
            emptytextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mAdapter.clear();
        if (blists != null && !blists.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(blists);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Testing: onLoaderReset is successfully called");
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

Custom Loader class

```
package com.example.shara.booklistapp;

import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class BlistLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Blist>> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = BaseAdapter.class.getName();
    private String mUrl;

    public BlistLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);

        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Testing: onStartLoading is successfully called");
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Blist> loadInBackground() {

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Testing: loadInBackground is successfully called");
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Blist> blists = null;
        try {
            blists = BookQueryUtils.fetchBookList(mUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return blists;
    }
}
```

XML that contains the ImageButton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_query_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="@string/hint" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_button1"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:text="Results" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptytextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the oncreateloader method to only execute when the search button is clicked and not otherwise.

How can this be achieved? Does my code need heavy modification or is it just something that I missed altogether.

I have previously asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930059/starting-a-method-on-a-button-click-in-android) but I didn't get any answers.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Book query utils is for the HTTP request and JSON parsing.

```
package com.example.shara.booklistapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shara on 12/17/2017.
 */

public final class BookQueryUtils {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = BookQueryUtils.class.getName();

    private BookQueryUtils() {

    }

    private static URL createURL(String search_query) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = null;
        String q = "q";
        try {
            final String base_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?";
            Uri final_Url = Uri.parse(base_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(q, search_query)
                    .build();
            url = new URL(final_Url.toString());
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "The final Url is" + url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Url could not be formed", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private static String theHTTPRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection connectionUrl = null;
        InputStream theInputStream = null;

        try {
            connectionUrl = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connectionUrl.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connectionUrl.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connectionUrl.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connectionUrl.connect();
            if (connectionUrl.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                theInputStream = connectionUrl.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(theInputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "could not make the connection");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem getting the requested data", e);
        } finally {
            if (connectionUrl != null) {
                connectionUrl.disconnect();
            }
            if (theInputStream != null) {
                theInputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder streamoutput = new StringBuilder();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String urlline = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (urlline != null) {
            streamoutput.append(urlline);
            urlline = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        return streamoutput.toString();
    }

    private static List<Blist> extractFeatureFromJSON(String BlistJSON) throws JSONException {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(BlistJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Blist> blists = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String a = "";
            JSONObject baseJSON = new JSONObject(BlistJSON);
            JSONArray items = baseJSON.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                Blist blistss = new Blist();
                JSONObject j = items.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject vInfo = j.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                if (vInfo.has("authors")) {
                    JSONArray athrs = vInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                    if (athrs.length() != 0) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < athrs.length(); k++) {
                            a = athrs.getString(k);
                            blistss.setAuthor(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (vInfo.has("imageLinks")) {
                    JSONObject thumbnail = vInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                    blistss.setImage(thumbnail.getString("thumbnail"));
                }
                blistss.setUrl(vInfo.getString("previewLink"));
                blistss.setTitle(vInfo.getString("title"));
                blistss.setPublisher(vInfo.getString("publisher"));
                blists.add(blistss);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not parse JSON", e);
        }
        return blists;
    }

    public static List<Blist> fetchBookList(String query_url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        URL url = createURL(query_url);
        String JSONResponse = null;
        try {
            JSONResponse = theHTTPRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not fetch data");
        }
        List<Blist> blists = extractFeatureFromJSON(JSONResponse);
        return blists;
    }
}
```

This is my adapter for the listview.

```
package com.example.shara.booklistapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by shara on 12/17/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blist> {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Blist> blists) {
        super(context, 0, blists);
    }

    public String rslt;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listitemview = convertView;
        if (listitemview == null) {
            listitemview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        }
        Blist blist = getItem(position);

        ImageView thumbnail = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_imageview);
        new imageLoader(thumbnail).execute(blist.getImage());
        progressBar = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.Image_Progress_bar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TextView title = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        title.setText(blist.gettitle());

        TextView author = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.author_textview);
        author.setText(blist.getauthor());
        TextView publisher = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.publisher_texview);
        publisher.setText(blist.getpublisher());

        return listitemview;
    }

    private class imageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public imageLoader(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call  initiateloader method to OnClick of imagebutton. ' loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);' to imagebutton click method.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH That did it, sir. Thanks a lot for your time and help. I called initloader and assigned the search query to the Booklistqueryurl variable inside the onclick of the image button.

Comment: It works fine on the first click of the search button but it does nothing on subsequent clicks. How can I refresh the list based on different keywords without restarting the app?

Comment: Did you tried with restart loader on querychange. [See Restarting a loader section](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Sir, I don't know if it will work as it is an edit text view that I have used. QueryChange is for Searchview's I think. I will try anyway.

Comment: Yes QueryChange will work only on searchview. Use code for 'Restarting a loader' inside onclick of imagebutton.

Comment: I tried that too, it refreshes the list view but with the same query results. I am unable to get it to use the latest search query. I tried Textwatcher and its override methods and the query variable is getting updated with the latest value in the edit text but the results remain the same.

Comment: Share your BookQueryUtils code. i will chk

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Sir, I have added the full code of my app in the original post. Please check when you have time and Thanks again for taking your time.

Comment: For me its working with restart loader. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated in Code**

Initially set empty query

```
private String Book_list_request_url = "";
```

Create method for "Search Click(imagebutton)"

```
public void Search(View v)
{
    Book_list_request_url = editText.getText().toString();
    loaderManager.restartLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
}
```

Add method to imagebutton

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_button1"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="Search"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I tried something similar but couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Welcome glad to help.!

Comment: Accept answer if it resolved the question. It helps others to solve for same issues.

Comment: Done, I was at my office